# Буфер приема сообщений сокета

Tags: python, сокет

Всем привет!
Как узнать на сколько заполнен буфер сокета, перед отправкой сообщений.

Библиотека socket python.
У меня бывает сообщения отправляются быстрее чем читаются. Это приводит к тому, что, например, десятое сообщение отправляется не полностью а только частично. Это не приводит к ошибке но данные теряются. Как перед отправкой проверить на сколько свободен буфер сокета?

Comment: методы которые могут отправить не все данные возвращают сколько именно они отправили. Если это значение меньше, чем то, что вы пытались отправить, остаток надо запомнить и отправить позже

Comment: Да, действительно. Почему то не увидел это в описании метода. Спасибо, раз знаю сколько отправил теперь дело за малым остается)